# Passing Credentials into powershell command

Tags: powershell

**I am trying to pass credentials into a PS-session's command**. However when I do, it returns with no information. It doesn't give me any error, it just brings up the next line on the interpreter.

**However if I try NOT to pass credentials and let the module ask me for the credentials, it will work.**

Here is the code:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "APASSWORD" -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("test@conglomo.com", $password)
$ses = New-PSSession -Name "test@conglomo.com" -ConnectionUri https://exchange.intermedia.net/powershell -ConfigurationName Hosting.PowerShell -Credential $Cred -Authentication Basic
Invoke-Command -Session $ses -ScriptBlock {Get-User -CredentialType "User" -Credential $Cred -AccountID 513258}
```

It returns nothing:

```
PS /home/tech/scripts> 
PS /home/tech/scripts>
```

Here is what happens if I DON'T add the `-Credential` option

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "APASSWORD" -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("test@conglomo.com", $password)
$ses = New-PSSession -Name "test@conglomo.com" -ConnectionUri https://exchange.intermedia.net/powershell -ConfigurationName Hosting.PowerShell -Credential $Cred -Authentication Basic
Invoke-Command -Session $ses -ScriptBlock {Get-User -CredentialType "User" -AccountID 513258}
```

It returns this:

```
PowerShell Credential Request: cmdlet Get-User at command pipeline position 1
Warning: A script or application on the remote computer EXCHANGE.INTERMEDIA.NET is requesting your credentials. Enter your credentials only if you trust the remote computer and the application or script that is requesting them.

Supply values for the following parameters:
User: test@conglomo.com
Password for user test@conglomo.com.com: **********

###MORE CODE THAT SHOWS MY REQUEST####
```

I thought I typed the credential inforamtion correct but let me know if I typed it wrong.
Here is the SYNTAX for the `Get-User` module when Used `Get-Help Get-User`:

```
SYNTAX
    Get-User [[-Identity] <String>] [-Force] [-HostingObjectType <HostingObjectTypes[]>] -CredentialType <String> -Credential <PSCredential> [-ResultSize <ResultSize>] 
    [-PropertiesToLoad <String[]>] -AccountID <Int32> [<CommonParameters>]
    
    Get-User [-Force] [-HostingObjectType <HostingObjectTypes[]>] -CredentialType <String> -Credential <PSCredential> [-Filter <String>] [-ResultSize <ResultSize>] [-PropertiesToLoad 
    <String[]>] -AccountID <Int32> [<CommonParameters>]
```

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Either pass ther credential variable to the scriptblock using `ArgumentList` or `$Using:Cred`

Comment: THIS was the answer! I would like to give you the answer but you answered my question in a reply. If you want to answer the question I can give you the points! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A scriptblock does not have access to local variables unless you specify them - your $Cred is a local variable

You can either use the `-ArgumentList` switch or tell it to use your local variable by specxifying `$Using:Cred`